# Python plot data to better perspecitve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a CSV file with some data in it that I need to create a line graph showing the temp changes along the time line per the date and time ranges in the CSV file along with the temp at each record.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser

with open("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\temdata.csv","r") as f:
    data = list(reader(f))

temp = [i[3] for i in data]
time = [parser.parse(i[1]) for i in data]

pyplot.title('Temperature changes over Time')
pyplot.xlabel('Time/hours')
pyplot.ylabel('Temperature')
pyplot.plot(time, temp)
pyplot.show()
```

I get this horribly scaled graph that does not put the data into perspective where it appears more meaningful and not just as if there is a huge spike at the times when the temp does increase.

I was able to put a dummy records in the file making it think that a temp reached 300 at one point to make it look at little better.

Are there any methods that are simple for a beginner with Python and plotting data with Python to utilize to scale the data differently without creating dummy data?

Is there something more robust that's not too difficult to use for plotting and graphing with Python to show tempurature over a time period?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible easy ideas come to mind:

1. Use a logarithmic y-axis to display your data. Replace your `plot()` entry with [`semilogy()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=semilogy#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy):

   ```
   pyplot.semilogy(time, temp)
   ```
2. Limit your temperatures to an upper bound, e.g. 120:

   ```
   temp = [min(120, int(i[3])) for i in data]
   ```

Note, I would avoid using `time` as a variable, as this is also a [`Python module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#module-time) name.

So your updated could would look like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser

with open("input.csv","r") as f:
    data = list(reader(f))

temp = [min(120, int(i[3])) for i in data]
time = [parser.parse(i[1]) for i in data]

pyplot.title('Temperature changes over Time')
pyplot.xlabel('Time/hours')
pyplot.ylabel('Temperature')
pyplot.plot(time, temp)
pyplot.show()
```

Giving you:
[image: upper bound]

Comment: Martin - Thanks for these ideas, very good info. The #1 isn't quite what I need but it does look better scale wise. I cannot get the syntax for #2 to work so I do this... `temp = [i[3] for i in data]` and then below that I have `temp = [min(t,120) for t in temp]` and it give me this error `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`. I'm a python noob so I may be doing something wrong but I tried several variations. Please let me know if you have any idea what I'm doing wrong based on the code in my question for the #2 suggestion. I appreciate you help!!

Comment: Try this: `temp = [min(i[3], 120) for i in data]`

Comment: Martin - I received the same error but I wanted to give you a link in case you are able to grab this test sample of data and then run it through Python on your side with the actual data I'm using to see for yourself of the error. Maybe this will be better so you can run it. Here's the link: https://justpaste.it/10oc4. I'm just using the syntax in my question and your #2 solution syntax and variations. If you get a moment, please let me know if you know what the problem may be. Thank you!!

Comment: It should work now, each entry first needed to be converted to an integer.

Comment: Thanks Martin - Just what I needed and was looking for so thank you for your help with this what seems to be such a minor task.